# Can't view embedded .jpg in html/php website

Tags: html, css, image, jpeg

I have a php/html website on my home server that has several embedded .jpg images in the style.css file I can view the website fine from the computer that is running the server but when I try to access it from another computer on my network I can't see the images I get a red x inside of a little box.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

```
#wrapper {
width:400px;
height:600px;
background-color:#3CF;
margin:0 auto;
background-image:url(wrapper.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}

#registerwrapper {
width:400px;
height:600px;

margin:0 auto;

background-image:url(register.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: might be better suited for serverfault?

Comment: My money's on using frontpage/dreamweaver/etc. with either a file:/// resolution or an absolute path to localhost. ;-) at any rate, the code in question would be helpful.

Comment: I uploaded the code.  I think the problem is the absolute path to the localhost.  How should I define it then?  And I am using Dreamweaver.

Comment: @user541597: HTML page too please (or atleast header with CSS `<link>`. And, if possible, the path the file is you're trying to do (in reference to the root of the site, e.g. if you're visiting `http://server2/admin/index.html` tell me it's path is `/admin/index.html`)

Comment: @user541597 the image URL is fine in the CSS and should show the images located in the same place as the CSS file - do you still have problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using an absolute path to the images. As it stands you're storing the images in the same location as you are storing your CSS

Comment: The images are in the same location as the css

Comment: I tried including the absolute path using (/Users/myname/Sites/image.jpg) and (Users/myname/Sites/image.jpg).  This cause the images not to even show on the local computer that I'm writing the code in.  Setting it back to (image.jpg) lets me see the pictures on the local computer but not on other computers on the network.